# Accessing relative images folder in a spring mvc from inside a controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am  trying to upload some files into my spring mvc web application. I have created an img folder inside WEB-INF and trying to put uploaded images into it. But i can not find the correct path to do that. Below code is not working.

```
//Doesn`t get into the  if (dir.isDirectory()) condition

Iterator<String> itr = req.getFileNames();
MultipartFile file = req.getFile(itr.next());
String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
File dir = new File("img");

if (dir.isDirectory()) {
            System.out.println("directory found");
            File serverFile = new File(dir, fileName);
            BufferedOutputStream stream;
            try {
                stream = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
                stream.write(file.getBytes());
                stream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
```

Comment: The container you are running you WebApp in should provide a place to store data (in case you don't use a DB). Which one are you using?

Comment: i am running my app in tomcat. i need to store the img on web server

Comment: Have you looked at [this](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/)?